# H310M PRO-VDH PLUS MOTHERBOARD AND i5-9400F won't turn on

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I built a PC with the following parts:

- [MSI H310M PRO-VDH PLUS](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7C09v1.0.zip)
- i5 LGA1151 i5-9400F 2.9 GHz
- 8GB Kingston DDR4 2400MHz CL15 HyperX Fury
- Satellite Pro-460 - 400w

there's no video after assembly. LEDs glow and fans spin, but the screen is blank.

I've read something about needing to update the mobo bios to support the i5-9400f, is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I assembled it all, it won't turn on the leds and fans turn on, but nothing is shown on the screen.

You didn't specify your GPU.  I mention that fact, since the [i5-9400F](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/190883/intel-core-i5-9400f-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html), does not have an Intel iGPU (i.e. Intel UHD Graphics 630).

> I've read something about needing to update the mobo bios to support the i5-9400f, is that true?

Based on the documentation provided by MSI.  Your motherboard supports the i5-9400F with firmware revision 7C09v10.  However, if your processor is the more recent stepping, your motherboard must be upgraded to 7C09v12.

[image]

As for the reason the firmware is required if you have the new R0 stepping for your processor.

> No one knows yet just what impact the new R0 stepping of Intel's 9th
>   Gen CPUs such as the Core i9-9900K, will offer, but one thing is sure
>   - you will need to update your motherboard's BIOS to use them as not doing so will cause Windows 10 to crash.
>
> However, having spoken to motherboard manufacturers MSI and Gigabyte
>   about the issue, it isn't as bad as I'd feared. **Unlike a generational
>   update, where you may not even be able to get into a motherboard's EFI
>   when using a new CPU and old motherboard BIOS, this time it looks like
>   you'll be able to at least boot your PC and enter the EFI to update
>   the BIOS with one of the new R0 CPU stepping-compatible versions.**

Source: [Intel's New 'R0 Stepping' 9th Gen Processors Will Crash Windows 10 Without New BIOS Update](https://www.forbes.com/sites/antonyleather/2019/03/29/intels-new-r0-stepping-9th-gen-cpus-will-crash-windows-10-without-new-bios-update/#28f690c9127d)

You should confirm you actually have a GPU installed in your system, and have connected your monitor to your GPU, instead of your motherboard.  In the end your system should be turning on, allowing to perform a firmware upgrade to the current revision, assuming the motherboard you just purchased even needs one.

Comment: lol I didn't know the cpu doesn't have iGPU, tested it with a regular gpu and it worked correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [motherboard manual](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7C09v1.0.zip) indicates there are three video ports; VGA, DVI-D, and HDMI. However, since the CPU will not drive them, they're idle. The i5-9400F has [no onboard process graphics](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/190883/intel-core-i5-9400f-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html).  You need a video card, or an CPU with processor graphics.

There is a [BIOS update](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/H310M-PRO-VDH-PLUS#down-bios) which will 'Update Microcode to support upcoming cpu' but its instructions don't say *which* CPU.

Comment: Intel 370 motherboards are universally forward compatible with 9th generation Intel Core processors.  9th generation was simply another tick generation.  A microcode update was required, but in this case, it does not have to be specifically be called out.

Comment: Does this mean that the external video card will be able to drive also the motherboard graphic ports?

Comment: No. The onboard ports are not connected when you have a CPU without processor graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the onboard "EZdebug LEDs" to see what the motherboard is complaining about.

Manual: https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7B24v2.0.zip

Page 16:

[image]

Page 7:
[image]

If, as others answered, your issue is that the i5 lacks a GPU, you'll probably see the VGA LED lit.